# Adding a legend to Overlay

Tags: legending, overlay

Does anybody know how to add plot legend to an Overlay in Mathematica? I had to make a plot with 2 different y-axis, so I produced two plots and joined them by Overlay, but now have no idea how to add legend.
Here's an example, and Legended does not work.

```
optsScale1 = 
  Sequence[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 16, 
   FontColor -> Black];
opts2 = Sequence[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20, 
   FontColor -> Black];  

pl1 = Show[
  Plot[E^x, {x, 1, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Purple, Thickness[0.005]]], 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 420,
  Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
  FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["x ", opts2], StyleForm["A", opts2]}, 
  RotateLabel -> True,
  FrameStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3], Thickness[0.003]},
  FrameTicks -> {{{3, StyleForm["3", optsScale1], {0.015, 0.0}}, {6, 
      StyleForm["6", optsScale1], {0.015, 0.0}}, {9, 
      StyleForm["9", optsScale1], {0.015, 0.0}}}, {{4000, 
      StyleForm["4", optsScale1], {0.015, 0.0}}, {8000, 
      StyleForm["8", optsScale1], {0.015, 0.0}}}, None, None}, 
  Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.9, 
  Epilog -> {Text[
     StyleForm["\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(3\)]\)", 
      optsScale1], {1, 13000}, {0, 0}], 
    Text[StyleForm["", opts2], {10, 16000}, {0, 0}], 
    Text[StyleForm["", opts2], {9, 0.4}, {0, 0}]}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{60, 60}, {60, 60}}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]


pl2 = Show[
  Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.6], Thickness[0.005]]], 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 420,
  Frame -> {False, False, False, True},
  FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["", opts2], StyleForm["", opts2], 
    StyleForm["", opts2], StyleForm["B", opts2]}, RotateLabel -> True,
  FrameStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3], Thickness[0.003]},
  FrameTicks -> {{None, {{3, 
       StyleForm["3", optsScale1], {0.015, 0.0}}, {6, 
       StyleForm["6", optsScale1], {0.015, 0.0}}, {9, 
       StyleForm["9", optsScale1], {0.015, 0.0}}}}, {None, None}}, 
  Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.9, 
  Epilog -> {Text[StyleForm["", optsScale1], {107, 740}, {0, 0}], 
    Text[StyleForm["", opts2], {10, 1}, {0, 0}], 
    Text[StyleForm["", opts2], {9, 0.4}, {0, 0}]}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{60, 60}, {60, 60}}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]

Overlay[{pl1, pl2}]
```

Comment: Provide the code (copy and paste InputForm) for a minimal example so that we can see to what you refer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The simplest way is manually making of the joint legend (with `Legended`) in one of the layers.

Comment: Take a look at [`ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) and its `"AxesSides"` option. That function allows you to easily make plots with two y axes by combining two or more plots, and it will automatically merge the legends of the individual plots

Comment: The definitions for `opts2` and  `optsScale1` are missing, so we can test your code